# How to get the array number with the name value in javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This is the json I'm trying to for loop through:

```
var json = {"series":[
          {
             "id":1448822,
             "name":"Buckinghamshire",
             "selected":true,
             "data":[
                [
                   19.23,
                   19.23
                ]
             ]
          },
          {
             "id":1448823,
             "name":"Cambridgeshire",
             "selected":false,
             "data":[
                [
                   38.46,
                   61.54
                ]
             ]
          }
    }
```

I've been trying to workout how to get the array position with the name selected with value true to the following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            var geoAreaSelected = serData[i].selected;
            if (geoAreaSelected === true) {
                this.series[i].data[i].setState('select');
            }
        };
```

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

Comment: that's not json. that's javascript. json is the value on the right-side of the `=` assignment operator.

Comment: @MarcB, and you're saying that JSON is not JavaScript. You provide wrong information here.

Comment: @lonut: show where in the json spec `var whatever = ` shows up?

Comment: "series":[{true},{false}} = [0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

```
var json = {
  "series":[
          {
             "id":1448822,
             "name":"Buckinghamshire",
             "selected":true,
             "data":[[19.23, 19.23]]
          },
          {
             "id":1448823,
             "name":"Cambridgeshire",
             "selected":false,
             "data":[[38.46, 61.54]]
          }
        ] // <= This was missing
    };

for (var i = 0; i < json.series.length; i++) {
  var geoAreaSelected = json.series[i].selected;
  if (geoAreaSelected === true) {
    console.log( json.series[i].data[i])
  }
};
```

Console logs `[ 19.23, 19.23 ]`

Comment: How would I just get the array with the name selected:true only?

Comment: So you only want the data when selected === true?

Comment: Yes I want the array number so that I can apply it the json.series[i].data[i]

Comment: `series[i].data[0][0] === 19.23` // The first element
`series[i].data[0][1] === 19.23` // The second element

...

Comment: `series[i].data[1] = i` // This sets the array index to the second element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over `json.series` and not over `json`

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.series.length; i++) {
  var geoAreaSelected = json.series[i].selected;
  if (geoAreaSelected === true) {
    json.series[i].data[i].setState('select');
    console.log(i); // <--- you can use the variable i to access ith object in the array
  }
};
```

Comment: ok so in each object there is a name called selected, how do I select it when it is set to true as an array for that object?

Comment: `json.series[i].selected` gets the `selected` part of each object. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: How was I get the array of the oject which has the 'selected: ture'

Comment: the variable `i` is what you're looking for.